# Dicom deformable image registration

Tags: python, vector, registration, imaging, medical-imaging

I have dicom files for two CT scans and deformable registration between them. I would like to ask how I can deform one CT scan based on the deformable registration file:
so far, I managed to extract the deformation vector field from the dicom file:

```
import pydicom, numpy as np 
from struct import unpack
ds = pydicom.read_file(fn) # fn: dicom deformation file.
v = ds.DeformableRegistrationSequence[0].DeformableRegistrationGridSequence[0].VectorGridData
values = unpack(f"<{len(v) // 4}f", v)
dim = B.GridDimensions
nx, ny, nz  = (dim[0],dim[1],dim[2]) # number of voxels in x,y,z direction 
# exctract the dx,dy,dz as per https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.20.3.html#sect_C.20.3.1.3
dx3d = values[0::3]
dy3d = values[1::3]
dz3d = values[2::3]
dx = np.reshape(dx3d,[nz,ny,nx])
dy = np.reshape(dy3d,[nz,ny,nx])
dz = np.reshape(dz3d,[nz,ny,nx])
```

I can plot the deformation field on each CT slice as can be seen in the image below.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsck7.png)

So, the remaining task is how to deform the CT data based on the deformation vectors (dx, dy, dz)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this question is almost a year old, but hey - better late than never!

You are actually pretty close to a solution. I think the missing piece of the puzzle is to switch from `numpy` for image manipulation to `SimpleITK`. This is an awesome python library available [here](https://simpleitk.org/) (and on `pip`).

```
import pydicom
import SimpleITK as sitk

from struct import unpack

# read DICOM deformable registration file
ds = pydicom.read_file(fn)

# extract the deformation values
dvf_vals_raw = ds.DeformableRegistrationSequence[0].DeformableRegistrationGridSequence[0].VectorGridData

# convert to numbers
dvf_vals = unpack(f"<{len(dvf_vals_raw) // 4}f", dvf_vals_raw)

# we need more image info to properly define the transform
reg = ds["DeformableRegistrationSequence"][0]["DeformableRegistrationGridSequence"][0]

dvf_grid_size = reg["GridDimensions"].value
dvf_grid_res = reg["GridResolution"].value
dvf_grid_origin = reg["ImagePositionPatient"].value

dvf_arr = np.reshape(dvf_vals, dvf_grid_size[::-1]+[3,])
dvf_img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(dvf_arr)
dvf_img.SetSpacing(dvf_grid_res)
dvf_img.SetOrigin(dvf_grid_origin)

# convert this to a transform
tfm = sitk.DisplacementFieldTransform(dvf_img)

# now we can finally apply the transform
# NB: image can be list of str for DICOM filenames, or NIfTI, etc.
img = sitk.ReadImage(image)

# NB: 2 -> linear interpolation, -1000 -> default (background) value
img_def = sitk.Transform(img, tfm, 2, -1000)
```

I hope this helps you and anyone else who finds this post!

Comment: Thank you @Robbie for your help. I  managed to go through all the steps apart from the last line as I got the following error: TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Transform'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    itk::simple::Transform::Transform()
    itk::simple::Transform::Transform(itk::TransformBase *)
    itk::simple::Transform::Transform(unsigned int,itk::simple::TransformEnum)
    itk::simple::Transform::Transform(itk::simple::Image &,itk::simple::TransformEnum)
    itk::simple::Transform::Transform(itk::simple::Transform const &)

Comment: I believe that this answer is close, but the last line should be: `img_def = sitk.Resample(img, tfm, 2, -1000)`.